# What is the pattern here? Rolls of five dice correspond to numbers

Tags: pattern, dice

What is the pattern in this puzzle?

[image: Roll 1: black 4, white 1, red 2, red 5, black 2. Answer is 4. Roll 2: white 5, black 6, white 4, red 5, red 6. Answer is 8. Roll 3: red 3, red 5, white 5, white 2, black 5. Answer is 14. Roll 4: white 6, black 6, red 1, red 4, white 2. Answer is 0. Roll 5: white 2, black 3, black 1, white 3, red 4. Answer is 4. Roll 6: white 2, red 2, black 6, red 6, red 5. What is the answer to Roll #6? Why?]

Comment: Can you please add the source of the puzzle? Puzzles given without proper credit may be deleted.

Comment: Potential duplicates: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/petals-around-the-rose, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63972/how-many-polar-bears-do-you-see, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58347/dutch-dice-puzzle.

Comment: Duplicate of the [Petals around the rose](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/petals-around-the-rose) puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

4. Each dot on the dice which surrounds an inner dot counts as one. A 5 counts as 4 and a 3 counts as 2. For example, roll 3 has 3 5's and 1 3. This would be 3 * 4 + 1 * 2 = 14. Roll 6 then contains only 1 5, which makes 1 * 4 = 4.

Comment: This answer is already given in the duplicate questions. Please don't answer duplicates, especially if your answer adds nothing new